# Saving widget options from class method

Tags: plugins, widgets, options

I have a widget class (derived from WP_Widget) that has a method (called via ajax) to update part of its options(the elements order) without the user to click "Save", to set the handler I do from the constructor:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_bgw_update_order', array(&$this, 'update_order'));
```

The `update_order` method does something similar to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/changing-widget-options-via-the-functions-php-when-there-are-no-hooks) question but it does not save the new options. My code:

```
public function update_order() {
    if (!is_admin()) die('Not an admin');
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['nonce']) ||
        !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], 'section-order-nonce')) 
        die('Invalid Nonce');
    $sections = $this->sections;
    $new_order = $_POST['section'];
    $new_sections = array();

    foreach($new_order as $v) {
        if (isset($sections[$v])) {
            $new_sections[$v] = $sections[$v];
        }
    }
    $this->sections = $new_sections;
    $settings = $this->get_settings();
    $settings[$this->number]['sections_order'] = $new_sections;
    $this->save_settings($settings);
    print_r($this->get_settings());
    die();
}
```

My `update` function does the usual stuff:

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['username'] = strip_tags($new_instance['username']);
    $instance['count'] = strip_tags($new_instance['count']);
    // [...]
    return $instance;
}
```

When I log `$settings` from `update_order` it has the right value:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [username] => username
            [count] => 0
            [title] => GitHub
            [skip_forks] => 1
            [show_octocat] => 1
            [sections_order] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Activity
                    [0] => Repositories
                )

        )

)
```

The `update` method doesn't get called and when I hit the "Save" button `$instance` (logged from the `form` method) doesn't have a `sections_order` key.

I come to the conclusion that `save_settings` doesn't do what I think it does.

How can I save the options from the `update_order` method? What I'm trying to achieve is to save `sections_order` without the user to click the "Save" button.

Comment: chrisguitarguy is right. You shouldn't need to write a save handler. I am wondering if the problem is that your handler is interfering with the default functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you writing your own save handlers for widgets? The `update` method your widget class will take care of this. You're saving per widget settings, exactly what the Widget API was designed to do.

```
<?php
class WPSE76224_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Create the widget options and such here, then call
        // $this->WP_Widget to let wordpress know about it.
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        // display the widget on the front end.
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        // The widget form in the admin area.
    }

    public function update($new, $old)
    {
        // Saves your data, called via AJAX. But your saving logic here.
    }
}
```

Since WordPress "loads" the widget class (you just register it with `register_widget`).  Chances are an instance of of the widget class is not created when you think it is -- on ajax requests, for instance.  If you do want to write your ajax handlers, you'll likely have to move that functionality outside of the widget class.

Further reading:

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API
2. http://pmg.co/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-widgets This is an older tutorial I wrote.  The "fetching the tweet" part doesn't work anymore due to changes a Twitter.

Comment: I din't include the `update` method because it never gets called when I do the ajax request from the client. What I want to do is to save the items order without the user clicking "save".

Comment: Revise your question to include that information and more about what you're trying accomplish. Were it me: a simple bit of JavaScript to `setTimeout` with a callback to "click" your widgets save button. Doesn't seem like something you really need to worry about, however -- just let people click save.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry if I didn't specify what I'm trying to do from the beginning.